# what is the shortest way to remove duplicate data/entries from an Array in Javascipt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an array,
const colors = ['red,'blue','green','yellow','red','blue'];

How should i remove all the duplicate colors in this array ?

I tried various methods , but those were very lengthy. i am expecting a straightforward solution for this problem.

Comment: This is already answered [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: let myArray=  ['red,'blue','green','yellow','red','blue'];
let unique = [...new Set(myArray)];

console.log(unique);